# Two ways for registration and starting service in Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to develop an application with GCM. I read the official document about GCM, but feeling like there are two ways for doing these.

### 1. As for registering an android device for GCM

It seems like there are two ways for registering a device to GCM.

"http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app"
says,

```
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
  GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
} else {
  Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
}
```

on the other hand, 
"http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#registering"
says,

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
// sets the app name in the intent
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", senderID);
startService(registrationIntent);
```

### 2. As for getting responses from GCM server and starting a service for handling them

Also, I'm feeling like there are two ways to start intent for handling the response.

"http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app" instructs like,

"make a sub class of com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService"

and implement

onRegistered(Context context, String regId)

onUnRegistered(Context context, String regId)

onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)

...etc.

While "http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html#registering" is described with,

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {                                                                                                                                                                                  
   @Override
   public final void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       MyIntentService.runIntentInService(context, intent);
       setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null, null);
   }   
}   


public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {                                                                                                                          

    private static PowerManager.WakeLock sWakeLock;
    private static final Object LOCK = MyIntentService.class;

    static void runIntentInService(Context context, Intent intent) {
        synchronized(LOCK) {
            if (sWakeLock == null) {
                PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                sWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "my_wakelock");
            }
        }
        sWakeLock.acquire();
        intent.setClassName(context, MyIntentService.class.getName());
        context.startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {
                handleRegistration(intent);
            } else if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
                handleMessage(intent);
            }
        } finally {
            synchronized(LOCK) {
                sWakeLock.release();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it right that there are two ways for doing both of the processes above, and I can use whichever way I want to?

Comment: Hi! I was also stuck on same issue. But in my case, I have two devices, Motorola running Android 2.2 version, and Samsung Galaxy S running 2.3 version. I have used first method. This method works fine on Motorola device but fails on my Samsung device saying "Service not available". Can you please tell me, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 3):

> It seems like there are two ways for registering a device to GCM.

There is only real way, which is your second approach. `GCMRegistrar` uses the second approach under the covers to implement the first approach.

> Also, I'm feeling like there are two ways to start intent for handling the response.

There is only one real way, which is your second approach. `GCMBaseIntentService` uses the second approach under the covers to implement the first approach -- this is why you need to register that `BroadcastReceiver` supplied by GCM in your manifest.

All else being equal, I recommend the first approach, as it is simpler and handles various issues for you. However, either way works.

Comment: Hello Sir! I was also stuck on same issue. But in my case, I have two devices, Motorola running Android 2.2 version, and Samsung Galaxy S running 2.3 version. I have used first method. This method works fine on Motorola device but fails on my Samsung device saying "Service not available". Can you please tell me, what could be the reason? (My project points to Google API 8 and not Android SDK 8).

Comment: @Shrikant: Assuming that your Samsung Galaxy S is running the original ROM, I do not know why you would get an error like that.